# Cross validation and standaridization in skitlearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I would like to find the accuracy of a sklearn classifier with K-cross validation. I can estimate the accuracy normally without cross-validation. However, how can I improve this code to do cross validation and apply a StandardScaler at the same time?

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=4)
pipe_lrSVC = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('clf', svm.LinearSVC())])
pipe_lrSVC.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = pipe_lrSVC.predict(X_test)
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the pipeline as the estimator input to [`cross_val_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score):

```
cross_val_score(pipe_lrSVC, iris.data, iris.target, cv=5)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick answer